# Book about space battles are more like submarine battles

Tags: story-identification, books, joe-haldeman

I remember reading an older sci-fi book a long time ago where space battles are fought using torpedoes that follow the target ship for light years on end. I would appreciate if somebody could help me recall what book it is. I think it is *The Forever War* by Joe Haldeman... could anyone confirm?

Comment: You're welcome to post an answer for your own question! It will help others looking for the same book in the future (I suggest removing the answer from the question and posting it as an answer)

Comment: I know I'm supposed to "wait" for an accept but in the post revisions you can see this is the story.

Answer (score 4):

Just so that this shows up as having an answer, [the original querent found](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/190665/2) that this was *[The Forever War](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21611.The_Forever_War)* by Joe Haldeman.

> The Earth's leaders have drawn a line in the interstellar sand—despite the fact that the fierce alien enemy that they would oppose is inscrutable, unconquerable, and very far away. A reluctant conscript drafted into an elite Military unit, Private William Mandella has been propelled through space and time to fight in the distant thousand-year conflict; to perform his duties without rancor and even rise up through military ranks. Pvt. Mandella is willing to do whatever it takes to survive the ordeal and return home. But "home" may be even more terrifying than battle, because, thanks to the time dilation caused by space travel, Mandella is aging months while the Earth he left behind is aging centuries.